# Can I use cloud function in storage rule?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Since there is no way to find size of a folder directly in rule, I have made a function which will determine the size of a file(in folder `xxx`) add that size to a child(`xxx`) in realtime database. Using this value, I can block user from adding data inside child (`xxx`) in realtime database. Since it is not possible to use to realtime database directly in storage rule. Can I call a function from storage rule which will check the child(`xxx`) in realtime database and return true or false based on the value
[image: blurred part is child name(xxx)]

Answer (score 1):

Security rules run in full isolation. There currently is no way to access other Firebase services from within the security rules of Cloud Storage.

It is a valid and common request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).